# MongoDB: querying for completion in documents containing an array of objects

Tags: mongodb

I have the following documents inside a `folders` collection:

```
folders: [
    {  _id : 1,
      docs : [
            { foo : 1,
              bar : undefined},
            { foo : 3,
              bar : 3}
             ]
    },
    {  _id : 2,
      docs : [
            { foo : 2,
              bar : 2},
            { foo : 3,
              bar : 3}
             ]
    },
    {  _id : 3,
      docs : [
            { foo : 2},
            { foo : 3,
              bar : 3}
             ]
    },
    {  _id : 4,
      docs : [
            { foo : 1 }
             ]
    },
    {  _id : 5,
      docs : [
            { foo : 1,
              bar : null }
             ]
    }
]
```

I need to be able to query the documents that do not have an `undefined` value, `null` value, or non-existent value for `docs.bar`. In the case above, the query should only return the document with `_id: 2`. I currently have a solution but I was wondering if there is a better way to query the documents.

My current solution:

`db.folders.find({$nor: [{"docs.bar": { $exists: false }}]})`

Comment: Turns out my solution returned a false positive. The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45189590/mongodb-querying-for-completion-in-documents-containing-an-array-of-objects/45195904#45195904) provided by @glitch however is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ...

```
db.folder.find({"docs.bar": {$exists: true}, "docs.bar": {$ne: null}})
```

... will return only those entries for which at least one of the sub documents in the `docs` array has a populated `bar` attribute. Note: in this query the two predicates are ANDed, I think that matches your requirements, it certainly returns the document with `_id: 2` from the set you supplied.